# Backup only certain filetypes

Tags: backup

I have set

```
vim.opt.backup = true
```

which keeps permanent backups. (Works as intended thus far.)

But I would like to exclude certain filetypes, or, even better, file extensions. (Say, .conf which I would prefer to set to keep the original with `patchmode`.)

Is there a way to do that? ( Exclude some extensions from `backup` and set only some extensions for `patchmode`.)

I am using neovim.

**Example:**

I have two files: an `example1.conf` and an `example2.text`

Setting `backup` will create an `example.conf.bak` and an `example.text.bak` (or example1.conf~ and example2.text~ as per the original behavior.)

Setting `patchmode` will create `example1.conf.orig` and `example2.text.orig` respectively.

Given my aim is to have `example1.conf.orig` amd `example2.text.bak`,

I read the `:h` on `backupskip`.

But (if I understand `:h` correctly,) `backupskip` applies **both** to `backup` and `patchmode`.

Therefore, if I was to add the extension .conf to `backupskip`, I would end up with no `example1` backup or original, and `example2.text.bak` along an `exampl2.orig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `backup` is a global option. The only way to keep it on but disable backups for certain files is to use `backupskip`, which is a list of file-patterns (see `:help 'backupskip'`). It could be difficult to accurately cover filetypes with such an option.

Be careful to add to the defaults rather than overwrite them, unless you don't like that it skips backups on files that are likely to be temporary.

Comment: Thank you. Backupskip indeed looks less than ideal. I hope it takes a *.conf value withour complaining, though it clearly doesn't seem designed to do that. Pretty big omission for an editor like vim / neovim. Any idea on how to (at the same time,) set patchmode for only some file types? Would autocmds have any effect?

Comment: The only other solution I can see is toggling it off, writing, and back on @Anthony. Looks like `patchmode` is also global. The pattern for `backupskip` should be able to use `*.conf`, since it's an `:help autocmd-patterns`

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: This comment is only meant to tag you, since I forgot to do so in my previous one. @D.BenKnoble

Comment: @Anthony explain which in more detail? Toggling + writing, `patchmode`, or `backupskip` + `*.conf`?

Comment: As I understand it, what you are proposing is setting backup and patchmode off, then using autocommands to turn them on in specific filetypes? I have a working knowledge of autocommands, but not enough to trust myself writing them for something as critical as backups. @Ben Also, wouldn't setting backups off potentially expose the files edited to risk of data loss. I remember reading something like that in the :h.

Comment: My _answer_ suggests setting `backup` on and using `backupskip`. My comment suggests that you do `:set nobackup | write | set backup` to avoid using a backup when writing a particular file. Same for `patchmode`, I guess

Comment: The autocommands aren't relevant except for the _patterns_ (see `:help backupskip` which links to `:help autocmd-patterns` IIRC).

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, though I feel it the way (neo)vim handles this is utterly confusing and it should be core functionality to **not** need to type such a command for every file type that needs to be handled differently. It is very strange we aren't allowed to set different lists for make backup and keep original based on filetype.

Comment: @Anthony file a feature request or submit a PR? For example, making such options buffer-local would do it.

Comment: @Ben I did, yesterday. Now it's up to the Neovim devs. :)